# Sort a list by another list... to organize matching pairs on the same row

Tags: excel

I know the title sounds a little funky. Basically this is what I'm trying to do: I have a large list of data and I'm trying to sort a small list off of the large list. I want the small list row number to match the large list row number. Currently it looks something like this:

```
aaa     aaa
bbb     ddd
ccc     eee
ddd     hhh
eee     kkk
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
kkk
```

What I want is something like this:

```
aaa     aaa
bbb    
ccc    
ddd     ddd    
eee     eee   
fff
ggg
hhh     hhh
iii
jjj
kkk     kkk
```

I didn't see anything like this in my research, so I was wondering if there's a simple way to do it in Excel. I tried a pivot table but couldn't get the results I want.

Comment: the output should look just like that... the values on the left column are unique and there is only one match in the right column.. so I want the two to match up on the same row if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a column between with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)>0,A1,),"")
```

copied down, then select first two columns, Copy, Paste Special, Values... over the top and delete third column.

Comment: awesome, I knew I was close! i used match and vlookup.. but not in this order. so the second a1 is where you put the name in right??

Comment: it works how i want it to.. both columns have unique values (as in none repeat, but every unique one in the right column is in the left)

Comment: oh one thing.. so if I try to get rid of the unsorted list it makes the sorted one blank (because its trying to do the same check). I dont want to manually type in the +1000 rows of stuff in now that its sorted. is there a way to copy the value without having to do it this way?

Comment: i just mean that now i have three columns... the two i had at first and the one extra one using your formula. i don't need the unsorted row now because i have the one using your formula. but if i remove that row, your formula doesn't work because it tries to do the same check, and returns a blank space

Comment: OH.. i gotcha.. I didn't see you said paste special lol... I tried pasting and i wasn't doin what I wanted. awesome!